# Racial Classification in US College Admissions Process

Tags: application, united-states

Elite U.S. universities are known to have affirmative action policies based on race and sex (and maybe religion?), in an effort to promote diversity.

I wonder how they can classify applicants based on race, given that it is sometimes difficult to clearly identify or prove one's race.

Is there a checkbox dedicated to race on an application form? For example, can a child of an Asian mother and a black farther choose to be categorized as black so as to improve the chance of admission?

I am asking these questions purely out of curiosity because I was born, raised and educated in Japan, a rather homogeneous society where no official records on race are kept.

I wonder the U.S. registry keeps residents' races, so it is relatively easy for Americans to obtain official documents proving their races.

As for religion, I guess it is even more difficult to obtain official documents. So, do applicants discretionally select their religions without the need to prove it, or does the U.S. government have religious records on its citizens? If applicants are free to choose, some unscrupulous individuals can choose a minority religion that gives a better chance, regardless of their true faith?

I have no idea about international applicants. Outside the U.S., it is very difficult and sometime impossible to officially prove one's race or religion, so the U.S. college admissions committee considers nationality only in the screening process?

I have no plan to apply for a U.S. university or have no interest in ideological stuff. But I would like to know practical aspects of affirmative action in American universities.

Comment: It relies entirely on self-identification. There are no legal definitions.

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but I hope I could know more about practical details. The stakes are high for applicants, and U.S. elite universities actually give some "advantages" to some groups in terms of SAT scores and grades. I am at a loss as to why the admissions committee accepts everything self-reported without checking its authenticity, given having a degree at a prestigious university boosts lifetime earnings power hugely. This screening process seems to be prone to abuse.

Comment: The point of racial or ethnic preferences is to adjust for discrimination, historical mistreatment and unequal access to opportunity. Trying to game your racial identification to "improve your odds" is unethical and takes opportunity away from someone who has been hobbled by discrimination. It's no different from faking a disability to get an accommodation. It certainly goes on, but most people have the decency not to do it.